# Press Certain Keys To Make Something Appear

Tags: javascript

http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/R4rWn/

```
    $(document).keypress(function(ev) {
    if (ev.which === 97 || ev.which === 65) { // 'a' or 'A'
         $('#mydiv').toggle();
    }
});
```

I have an example up top to show what I mean, but I'm looking for something more diverse. As in if you type the word "example" all within a certain amount of time the set div will show and stay until "example" is typed again. I don't have much JavaScript knowledge so I don't know how to achieve this.

Comment: Are you really just looking for the Konami code ?

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure what that means, but if you're referencing what I think Facebook did in around 2009 where you press certain buttons "example" happens than yes.

Comment: @Deervious I have something for you in the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an implementation I made. This is in no way the best implementation, and I'm sure there's a bug. There is the fear that as the user is typing the buffer will clear, but I'm sure you could find a way around that. But it should hopefully give you enough ideas to continue.

```
// Stores keys pressed in order
var buffer = [];

// Every keypress shove the key in a buffer and call the compleyKeyCheck() function which will assess the buffer
$(document).keypress(function(ev) {
    buffer.push(ev.which);
    console.log("Just pushed " + buffer[buffer.length - 1]);
    complexKeyListen('example');
});

// Compares the buffer to the required string
function complexKeyListen(string){
    var i;
    for(i = 0; i < string.length; i++){
        console.log("Char in buffer " + buffer[i]);
        if (buffer[i] !== string.charCodeAt(i)) { 
            break;
        }
    }
    if(i == string.length){
        $('#mydiv').toggle();
        buffer= [];
    }
}

// Auto clear the buffer every ten seconds.
setInterval(function(window){
    console.log('Cleared buffer');
    buffer = [];}
,10000);
```

Comment: Hey I will try this code out and see if I can get it working and also thank you for taking the time to reply and sharing your code. I really appreciate you taking the time out of your life to help me.

Comment: Hey thanks a bunch I get the idea of it and I got it working now. Much appreciated and I wish I could give you an upvote, but apparently I need 15 rep. If I ever get 15 rep I will be sure to come back and repay you for the help!

Comment: here's an alternative fiddle which clears the que after 1 second of not getting any key pressed. Idea is almost the same as Cygwinnian did. http://jsfiddle.net/Sab8q/13/

Comment: @Marvin Hey thanks for the help also, I will try out your code also!

Comment: @MarvinSmit Nice. I was hoping someone would come along and patch it :)